# What are apps 10110 & 10109?

Tags: applications

On my galaxy S2, the mobile data usage shows two applications 10110 and 10109 consuming a lot of data. Does anyone know what these apps are? Or how I can find out? 
I am running jellybean 4.1.2 on Samsung Galaxy S2.

Comment: Can you see those apps in Settings -> App?

Comment: No, I can't  see them there.

Answer (score 1):

That are most likely not app *names*, but their "user IDs" (and the system is unable to match a name).

On a rooted device, you could find out more on those by executing

```
ls -l /data/data | grep 10110
```

(which should show you the data directory of the app owned by that user, together with some more data). Investigating that directory might give you an idea: its name is the package name, which you could even lookup at Google Play:

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=<package_name>
```

While that's unlikely to find the app (or your system really is in trouble not being able to match the two), it's at least worth a try. In case nothing is found, you can investigate that directory's content to make a "good guess" what it might be about. Also, the name of the directory itself might already have given you a clue.

---

I will give you an example (from one of my extracted Nandroid backups). Let's say `ls` turned up `com.motorola.android.fota` on a Motorola device. So by the fact it's a Motorola device, and the package name starting with `com.motorola.android` one can deduce it's a system app build by the manufacturer. Assuming one doesn't connect the `fota` with anything, in the subdirectory `databases` one finds two SQLite files. I checked the `config.db` and saw it has two tables, at least one of them seemingly all about updates (auto_update_interval, auto_update_enable, and more). The second one is `fumo.db` and seems to hold information about packages. So this is most likely an app responsible for updating apps -- and if you not already know, "FOTA" stands for "Firmware Over The Air update".

---

However, to do that your device must be rooted (users other than root it won't permit to browse the `/data/data` directory).